# Can I access the methods defined in an implicit Proc in a Ruby method?

Tags: ruby, function, methods, proc

Suppose I have the following code:

```rb
def my_test(&fn)
    #code goes here
end

my_test {
    def my_cool_fn(a, b)
        a + b
    end
}
```

**Question:** Is there some way, from within the body of `my_test`, to access particular methods defined by the block defined and passed to it as `fn`?<sup>†</sup>

Here's what I've tried. I was inspired by the way `Struct` is usually defined:

```rb
Person = Struct.new(:name, :age) {
    def greet
        puts "Person #{name} says hello!"
    end
}
mike = Person.new("Mike", 37)
mike.greet
```

I know it is possible to use this in the following way to achieve an effect similar to what I want, however, incredibly inelegant.

```rb
def my_test(&fn)
    ex_struct = Struct.new(:dummy, &fn)
    instance = ex_struct.new
    puts "The result is: #{instance.my_cool_fn 3, 6}"
end

my_test {
    def my_cool_fn(a, b)
        a + b
    end
}
```

Which will print the expected `The result is: 9`. However, this seems kind of hacky, and I was wondering if there was a more "proper" way of achieving this result.

(† This question is, for my purposes, purely hypothetical and for amusement's sake; there isn't some greater problem I'm trying to solve, just trying to learn more about this language.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby is an object oriented language. Every method needs to be defined on something (some object). You need to choose where you want to define that method.

You can define it on the same object `my_test` is currently defined (`main`) by just evaluating the block.

```
def my_test(&fn)
  instance_eval(&fn)
end

my_test {
  def my_cool_fn(a, b)
    a + b
  end
}

my_cool_fn(1,2) #=> 3
```

Or you could use a new class/module (e.g. `Struct`) and define it there as you did.

Comment: `instance_eval`/`instance_exec` are certainly interesting - do they necessarily leak scope globally?

Comment: No. The current scope of instance_eval is global (`main`) since that's where `my_test` is defined and we don't encapsulate the eval. If you want to encapsulate it, create a capsule around it. Either an (anonymous) class or module and eval it into there instead of current scope.